# Should UI Element Code be at the top or bottom of a webpage?

Tags: php, html, web

I can't seem to find a straight forward answer. "Closer to the header" or "closer to the footer" with some sort of explanation is what I need.

Let's say I've got a PHP driven website with the main files being header/content/footer.php

If I'm creating a "branded" "app-like" website (cheap illustration here)

where should the external "UI" elements be coded? Is there a best practice to include in closer to the header (rendered first) or near the footer (rendered last)?

http://i47.tinypic.com/29vhzx5.png - let's assume gray is UI elements and blue is individualized content/sidebar area?

Just need some assistance of where that should be coded as a best practice, if it matters at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we talk about UI, it comes first and before functionality. UI elements comprise of markup and CSS so obviously it should be rendered first, the functionality pieces should come last because it is important to let users first see the UI and after that let them interact with it. So you should use a render first policy.
Hope that helps